# Using a backgroundworker to show a loading gif

Tags: c#, webforms, backgroundworker

I am in need of your collective wisdom, I am needing to implement a background worker to show a loading or waiting gif in a website built in webforms. A lot of the info I've come across for BG Workers has been for winforms, I'm still fairly new to C#, so I'm not very confident in applying the info to webforms. I've already tried using a jquery solution, but it isn't quite what I'm needing.

I know I need to show some code of what I've tried, but I don't have any (apologies). I would greatly appreciate some hand holding to build this out, but if you are not a big fan of having your personal space violated, a point in the right direction and a hearty, "Vayo con Dios" would be appreciated too. Thank you

Comment: If I may ask - why use a background-worker for that? Putting up a gif-image does not require continued execution on the part of your server. It is the end-user's browser that shows that gif-image as an animation. From your server's perspective, it simply throws the image-file up and is done.

Comment: I agree with James, a GIF is perfectly acceptable in a case like this. If you really wanted to avoid that you could make it in CSS. there are plenty of libraries and sites that will auto generate the one you need http://cssload.net/

Comment: Since you are using webforms you can use UpdatePanel controls and display 'loading gifs' with UpdateProgress controls https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx

Comment: @James Hurst My initial solution was using jquery to show an animated gif on page load and it works, it fires and shows the animation. However, it doesn't fire immediately, when a button is clicked nothing happens, but when the new page is rendered, then it shows up. Also, the gif will fire on every page load. I just need it to fire on long process loads and immediately. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: I think you need to enable partial-page rendering and use controls designated for that (UpdatePanel for example) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx

Comment: @kirodge dumb question, but could I do this on the masterpage? Wrpa the contentPlaceHolder in an Update panel and tie the updateProgress control to it. I ask because i tried that, and it didn't work, maybe I just set it up wrong. I wanted to use the masterpage so it would extend to all the pages tied to it.

Comment: Yes, you can add it to the master page. Did you remember to add a ScriptManager control to the master page?

Comment: yes, I do have a ScriptManger. Right beneath my opening form tag

Comment: For additional reference UpdatePanel on a master page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's funny, that's exactly the page I'm looking at now...not currently, but prior to reading your comment

Comment: Good luck then ;) If it still doesn't work for you, maybe you can edit your question (or ask a new one) and show us what you got so far. (I'll be sleeping now)

Comment: I see. I'm sure you're already aware, but just in case you're making this one little mistake: Your 'loading' image should not be associated with the new page, but rather with the page that you're leaving, in response to the button-click or whatever user-action is causing the system to transition to a new page.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but how do I associate it with the previous page

Comment: I want to thank you guys for your input and say that I found a solution that might work and is simple enough.